# Summation of values with odd index in a sequence

Tags: notation

Given a sequence of numbers $S = \langle s_1,\dots,s_n \rangle$ I want to sum all the elements of S that the index is odd.

Would the following be a good notation or is there a more compact (and better) way to write that?
$\sum_{i=0,i \in 2\mathbb{N}-1}^{|S|} s_i$

Thanks!

Comment: Those would be the elements with even index.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just edited.

Answer (score 4):

How about $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor} s_{2i+1}$?

Comment: Maybe if I simplify the upper bound! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think $i=0,i\in 2\mathbb N$ looks confusing.  Better might be
$ \displaystyle \sum_{{i=0} \atop {i \ \text{even}}}^n s_i $ or  $\displaystyle\sum_{{i=0} \atop {i \ \text{odd}}}^n s_i $

Comment: Seems a good solution. Is the "i even" a notation commonly used? Thanks!